# bucket aggregation/bucket_script computation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

How to apply computation using bucket fields via bucket_script?  More so, I would like to understand how to aggregate on distinct, results.

For example, below is a sample query, and the response.

What I am looking for is to aggregate the following into two fields:

1. sum of all buckets dist.value  from e.g. response (1+2=3)
2. sum of all buckets (dist.value x key)  from e.g., response (1x10)+(2x20)=50

**Query**

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "field": "value"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "sales_summary":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"qty",
                "size":"100"
            },
            "aggs":{
                "dist":{
                    "cardinality":{
                        "field":"somekey.keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Query Result:**

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "sales_summary": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 10,
                    "doc_count": 100,
                    "dist": {
                        "value": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": 20,
                    "doc_count": 200,
                    "dist": {
                        "value": 2
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [sum bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html), which is a pipeline aggregation to find the sum of response of cardinality aggregation across all the buckets.

**Search Query for sum of all buckets dist.value from e.g. response (1+2=3):**

```
POST idxtest1/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sales_summary": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "qty",
        "size": "100"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dist": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "pageview"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sum_buckets": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "sales_summary>dist"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Response :**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "sales_summary" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 10,
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "dist" : {
            "value" : 2
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 20,
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "dist" : {
            "value" : 3
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "sum_buckets" : {
      "value" : 5.0
    }
  }
```

---

For the second requirement, you need to first modify the response of value in the bucket aggregation response, using [bucket script aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html), and then use the modified value to perform bucket sum aggregation on it.

**Search Query for sum of all buckets (dist.value x key) from e.g., response (1x10)+(2x20)=50**

```
POST idxtest1/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sales_summary": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "qty",
        "size": "100"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dist": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "pageview"
          }
        },
        "format-value-agg": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "newValue": "dist"
            },
            "script": "params.newValue * 10"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sum_buckets": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "sales_summary>format-value-agg"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Response :**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "sales_summary" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 10,
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "dist" : {
            "value" : 2
          },
          "format-value-agg" : {
            "value" : 20.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 20,
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "dist" : {
            "value" : 3
          },
          "format-value-agg" : {
            "value" : 30.0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "sum_buckets" : {
      "value" : 50.0
    }
  }
```

Comment: based on  your option 2 response, I realized that I need to clarify that item.  I was expecting sum_buckets value to be **80** (10x2)+(20x3)=80 because computation I was looking for is (dist.value x key)

Comment: passed down a field with value from _key and used it.